# Execute hadoop jar from PHP Server fails. Permission denied

Tags: php, hadoop, jar, hbase

I am trying to execute a jar file to do a simple query on my HBase database, from a PHP Server, so i can print the results to a webpage.

PHP Server in configured with same username as hadoop user, and same group too.

The PHP exec command is:

```
exec("bash /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop  jar myjar.jar my.package.MyClass   2> php_error.log", $result);
```

I get this exception when i try to exec the command(in the php_error.log):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:115)
```

I know its related to permissions, but even with 777 on my HDFS, and on hadoop installation folders, it doesnt work.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Also, where this temp file wants to be created?
Hadoop dir? hdfs? Where?

Edit:
running this locally, it works perfectly! no permission errors!
    hadoop  jar myjar.jar my.package.MyClass

Comment: It looks to me like jar is trying to make a temp copy of the file. Maybe you don't have permissions on the folder where the copy should be saved

Comment: i created a folder in my server, put jar in it, and gave it recursively full permissions. still got this message! I m afraid is hadoop related. php server has to run as the hadoop user i think..

Comment: the tmp dir can be anywhere on the filesystem, only creating a new folder and give recursiveley full permission is not enough. You have to find out where your hadoop.tmp.dir is located

Comment: i know where the tmp dir is. what to do next? btw when running the jar locally(w/o my php server), it runs okay!! (see how in last line in my post -edited)

Comment: I assume you where not logged in with your www-data user when trying this, am i right?

Comment: no. the changed www-data user (username: apache), to the hadoop username: hduser. and php code prints hduser. which has access and runs successfuly all hadoop tasks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP is ok. The problem is, that the command you are running is trying to copy the file to the hadoop.tmp.dir. It's default location is `/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}`. You have to give the permissions to **that** folder too, or the full `/tmp/hadoop` directory recursively

**Edit:**

Figured out that apache isn't a valid user in that case. The solution is to create a new user, add it to hadoop group, set permissions to jar, and hadoop.tmp.dir and change the webpage owner to the created user

Comment: my tmp directory is /app/hadoop/tmp ! app/hadoop has -R 777 permissions. /app has 775 permissions . btw thank you Bernhard

Comment: And it's still not working? Are you sure there is no /tmp dir? Are you logged on as root?

Comment: no i am not logged in as root. (for hbase). And is working perfeclty from terminal. from php server isnt! :( Server is on same machine with hmaster, and logged in with same username as hadoop user!

Comment: I am sure, the problem is, that when you run the command from php, you run it as another user, and this user has definitley no write+execute rights on the hadoop tmp dir. Thats the reason why the Exeption `at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1879)` occures

Comment: something weird/interesting. copied jar in ~ dir(of hduser), and in php error i got /root/a.jar file not found...

Comment: what happens if you copy jar to ~ of user apache?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24074/discussion-between-bernhard-poiss-and-paschalis)